# Identificación y reutilización de id's que hayan sido eliminados con php

Tags: php, laravel, contador

Estoy intentando generar un sistema de numeración que identifique registros que hayan sido eliminados, y en caso que así sea, los llene.

Por ejemplo, Actualmente mi código es el siguiente:

```
$nro_cite = Nota::where('id_area', $request->id_area)
                  ->where('id_documento', $request->id_documento)->max('nro_cite');
if($nro_cite){
// Si esta definido se incrementa en 1
$nro_cite = $nro_cite + 1;}
else{ // Si no esta definido, su valor sera 1
$nro_cite = 1;}
```

Supongamos que genero 3 registros, luego borro el segundo de esos 3.

Si en esas condiciones genero un nuevo registro, se le asignará nro_cite = 4, quedando nro_cite=2 vacío.

Hay alguna manera de que se nro_cite =2 no quede vacío? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es que en realidad en una aplicación cuando tú borras algo, no lo borras. En producción "borrar" significa poner un flag a true, pero los datos *siempre* se quedan. Sea en esa tabla, sea en una tabla aparte que uses para almacenar datos "borrados", pero y si en algún momento necesitas restaurar una entrada en la base de datos y resulta que ya metiste otra (con lo cual, sustituiste el valor anterior)? Hay un motivo por el cual los índices autoincrementales no *"rellenan los huecos"*, y es para evitar andar machacando valores (además de la lentitud de buscar qué huecos hay libres, claro)

Comment: Yo crearía un registro de nro_cites disponibles. Cuando borres, el nro_cite que has borrado lo incluyes en la tabla de nro_cites disponibles: cuando tengas que asignar un id, sencillamente coges de ahí el menor valor: si no devuelve nada, entonces creas uno..... aunque pensándolo bien, una estrategia posible sería generar en esa tabla de disponibles un buen lote de ellos (digamos un millón) y así el programa queda más sencillo.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando borramos registros en una tabla de la base de datos, de tipo SQL, tenemos dos opciones: borrado (acción por defecto) que gestiona el sistema de gestión de BD, en el que los registros se eliminan, y borrado "blando", en el que los registros se "marcan" (en Laravel se llama [Soft Deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#soft-deleting)). El borrado blando se hace generalmente por que es más eficiente "marcar" que eliminar, siempre se pueden programar borrados de los registros marcardos en caso necesario.
Lo que estamos ejecutando es una sentencia de tipo UPDATE, no DELETE. En este caso no tendrías "Ids libres" entre registros.

En cuanto a reutilizar IDs de registros borrados... El sistema gestor de BD, suponiendo que tengas IDs de tipo numérico autoincremental, que es lo normal, va generando IDs de forma automática que aumentan en 1 (o lo que se indicó al crear la tabla) la ID de cada nuevo registro. Puedes usar IDs eliminadas, es decir crear nuevos registros usando IDs de registros que se eliminaron, ***si especificas esas IDs cuando guardas los nuevos registros*** (dentro de la sentencia INSERT), es decir que indicas la ID que se va a usar, no se va a generar automáticamente, lo que puedes hacer siempre que la ID este libre.